# How to check from code that the Build currently is in Alpha, Beta or Production State?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

So i have pushed my `apk` file on Alpha, if everything goes well, i will update it to Production. Here is the thing, I am not uploading a new build for production, i am just pushing my Alpha build to Production.

And I have defined some `URL's`, that have some dummy data for Alpha release. Right now i need to change all URL's before pushing the build to production.So There is a possibility that i may forget to change 1 or 2 URL's.

All i need to know is a possibility to add a check in my code, that can do the Job for me. I google it, but failed to find out any thing related. Kindly guide me, if there is any way, we can know that the build currently is in Alpha, beta, or Production state.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but for best practice, [versioning](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) is a critical component of your app upgrade and maintenance strategy. You can check this [tutorial](http://blog.cubeactive.com/app-version-number-android-tutorial/) on how to get the version of the app. You might also want to check the document about [Prepare for Release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html) and [Launch Checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#support-users)